# OkHttp: How to set route/host specific connection limits?

Tags: okhttp

I'm looking to set per route/host connection limits using the OkHttp client. I didn't find such an option in their Javadoc, but thought I'd ask. Is it possible? It is possible using the Apache client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn’t possible today. The closest approximation we have is using multiple OkHttpClient instances and managing that yourself. Note that each ConnectionPool instance keeps its own thread for eviction.

We might be able to build this with [more capable interceptor chains](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3039).

Comment: When you say "we might be able to build this", I' assume you're talking to yourself and "we" doesn't include me :)